# Twitter Search API (rates) changed?

Tags: r, twitter, rate, limits

Some time ago I created an application with R-studio which scrapes tweets from Twitter. I was able to get more than 100 tweets with the first data capture.

Today I was trying to use my application again but unfortunately it doesn't get any tweets anymore. Even when setting the number of tweets to 1 I get:

```
    Warning in doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
    1 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0
```

Are there any changes made to the Twitter Search API or something? I tried making a new Twitter App but it makes no difference; I can't get tweets anymore.

I have checked the rate_limit_status and that seems to be OK:         "search": {
            "/search/tweets": {
                "limit": 180,
                "remaining": 178,
                "reset": 1501970478
            }

This is the code I am using for the authentication in R studio:

```
  token <- ""
  setup_twitter_oauth("XXXX", "XXXX",
                      access_token="XXXX",
                      access_secret="XXXX")
  token <- get("oauth_token", twitteR:::oauth_cache)
  token$cache()
```

&& for getting the result:

```
tweets_result <- searchTwitter(paste("#",input$hashtag,sep=""), n = 1, lang = 'nl', since=max_date, sinceID = last_id)
print("________________________tweets_______________________")
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to include the snippet of code (authorization minus keys) which initialize and pull the tweets so that people can give meaningful help.

Comment: Twitter support may better answer your question

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/community

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have edited my initial post based on those.

Comment: I noticed the Twitter rate limits are still behaving as before but I guess my application is somewhat broken due to the filters I implemented based on the time.    ( max_date <<- max(history$created)
    if(max_date == -Inf) max_date <- NULL
    else max_date <- substr(max_date, 1, 10)) guess something goes wrong there suddenly..

Comment: The Search API only supports a seven day history window, so if your dates are not in that window, or there are no results in that time frame, then you will get 0.